# Conditional Format to highlight every other row on a sheet that adapts when filtered

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, excel-filter

Right now, I have a sheet where I've applied a conditional format formula to my sheet which colors every other row in my range.

=AND(ISODD(ROW($C3)),ISBLANK($C3)=FALSE)

However, I often have to filter the range for various criteria and was wondering if there's a better way to do this so that every other row remains highlighted despite the filter?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you considered using a Table, as described here? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c

Comment: You mean that with rows `1,2,3,4,5` then rows `2,4` are colored, but if `3` is filtered out then rows `2,5` are colored?

Comment: exactly @harrymc

Answer (score 4):

Use SUBTOTAL to count the number of visible rows on a variable range:

```
=AND(ISEVEN(SUBTOTAL(3,$A$1:$A1)),$A1<>"")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: brilliant. Worked like a charm. Thank you